# Can I use llvm in my commercial application?

Tags: llvm, commercial-application

Can I use llvm in my commercial closed-source application without changing the source code of llvm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. LLVM uses the University of Illinois/NCSA
Open Source License. It states:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal with the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> ```
> * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
>   this list of conditions and the following disclaimers.
>
> * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
>   this list of conditions and the following disclaimers in the
>   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
>
> * Neither the names of the LLVM Team, University of Illinois at
>   Urbana-Champaign, nor the names of its contributors may be used to
>   endorse or promote products derived from this Software without specific
>   prior written permission.
> ```

For more details and some restrictions regarding the license see [Copyright, License, and Patents](https://llvm.org/docs/DeveloperPolicy.html#copyright-license-and-patents)